# Recursive boxplot in R returning invalid variable type error

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, boxplot

I'm trying to plot multiple boxplots in R within a for loop but can't reference columns in the dataset using the `data.frame[column]`as it returns the following:

`Error in model.frame.default(formula = e[1] ~ e[2]) :`
`invalid type (list) for variable 'e[1]'`

The following code returns the same error that I'm getting:

```
x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20)
e <- data.frame(x, y)
boxplot(e[1] ~ e$y)
```

Any suggestions? I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

**1.** As pointed out by @Sven Hohenstein, your `boxplot` call needs to reference data.frame columns correctly.

**2.** I think that you want two side by side boxplots (x and y), not x ~ y. For example:

```
# All these commands are equivalent:
boxplot(e$x, e$y)
boxplot(e[[1]], e[[2]])
boxplot(e[, 1], e[, 2])

# Probably not what you want:
boxplot(e$x ~ e$y)
boxplot(x ~ y, data=e)
```

Comment: Yep referencing using dataframe[[x]] sorts it out

Comment: I am plotting variable x with respect to the treatments y ie (x~y), side by side (x, y) would treat y as a variable and plot it alongside x instead of plotting x with respect to the treatments.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I was previously looking at your example data where both x and y are continuous variables, but really you have y as a categorical variable.

Answer (score 1):

To access column `x` of data frame `df`, use

```
df[[x]]
```

or

```
df[ , x]
```